# Do Vulcans lose muscle and bone mass after living long term on Earth?

Tags: star-trek, biology

It was said that Vulcans are stronger than humans because the planet Vulcan's gravity is 1.4G (according to [Memory Beta](https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Vulcan_(planet))), which requires stronger muscles to move around. But we also know that humans lose muscles and bone density if they spend too much time in lower gravity, say space stations or Mars. OK, humans have not actually been to Mars yet, so we can't say too much about how much muscles and bone density humans lose after living long term on Mars. So do Vulcans also lose some muscle strength and bone density after living for years on Earth (or a predominantly human ship which most likely has 1G artificial gravity), having adapted to Earth climate? EU answers are also accepted.

Comment: What you say makes sense, but I do not remember anything about this being mentioned anywhere.

Comment: Does Vulcan have higher gravity than Earth, and if so, is it 1.4 g?  Done't state that as a fact unless you can quote a canonical source (movie or episode) stating it.  If Vulcan has a significantly higher gravity in addition to heat and thin air, we might wonder how Amanda managed to survive all those decades there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on TV & movie evidence, I'd say the answer is **NO**.

We know from The Original Series that Mr Spock lived for several years on the Enterprise and doesn't appear to have suffered any serious side-effects. In [Amok Time](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cUHFnktxW1o), he seems to be every bit as strong and agile as in any other episode's fight scene. What's interesting to note is: McCoy states to Kirk, "If the heat doesn't get you, the thin air will", but Kirk is nòt negatively affected by Vulcan's higher gravity. (In reality, this is because the show was produced in the mid-1960s, when no one really knew what effect gravitic variance would have, though the effects of heat & thin air were already well known.) We know from the newer Star Trek movies that a rather younger Mr Spock can jump around and fight very well having lived on Earth for a period of time with no apparent ill effects.

**Rationale:**
I suspect that by the 23rd century, medical science shall have advanced sufficiently that minor complicating factors like gravity will have been dealt with. After all, you can just pop a pill and [grow a new kidney](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4qgqGWS8qSc)! I see no reason to suspect that some kind of gene or other therapy will "cure" the bone & muscle issues that come of living or working in radically different gravitic environments.

Vulcan sciences are also rather more advanced than Human. They have probably already solved the problem of living in other gravitic environments. If they ever had that problem to begin with.

Comment: As we've seen in DS9, gravity can be adjusted in crew quarters, so maybe Vulcans up it a little in private when staying in lower-grav environments

Comment: In their quarters, maybe in the gym...but the issue is basically ignored on the show.

Comment: their biology may not work this way. i believe there are animals on Earth that have muscles that do not respond to exercise (because of very short life spans like among insects) but rather are at their peak functionality at birth. and even among mammals, some species can run almost from birth -- those "running" muscles must have been strong without exercise.